# Delete row if 2 conditions are met - change in time and same value in another column

Tags: excel, vba, timedelta

I am trying to code a loop in excel vba to do the following:

I have a column that is a long date + time.  I have another column that has a text string.

I want to delete the entire row IF the change in time (row - row above) is less than 0:00:05 AND the value of the string is the same (row vs row above)

I'm running into problems with the IF condition, especially the 5 second portion, it doesn't like it...

```
For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

  'We check the values in the D column
   With .Cells(Lrow, "D")

      If Not IsError(.Value) Then

        If (Cells(i,"D") - Cells(i-1,"D")) > (0:00:05) AND (Cells.Value(i,"F") = 
        Cells.Value(i-1,"F")
        Then .EntireRow.Delete

      End If

  End With

Next Lrow
```

OK, the code above sucks.  I am going to explore a different tack.  I want to compare column F - with the current cell to the one below it.  If they are the same, then trigger the next clause - seeing if current cell in D is < 0:00:05 seconds different from the one below it, if so, then delete (or store information to delete outside the loop).

If the two cells in F are not the same, then skip to the next cell.

That make more sense?  Let me work up a code and post it here.

Comment: First thing I noticed is that your counter variable is `LRow`, but you referenced `i` in your `If` statement ... I haven't looked beyond that, though....

Comment: John - Good catch - the i wasn't even declared at the top, but even with that edit, it still doesn't like the IF line with the cells.  I'm thinking using range might be a better alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Your time will need to be represented as a number as dates in Excel are calculated as the number of days since a given date (e.g. today is 41458 days from 1st Jan 1900). So divide a day by 24 to get one hour and then by 12 to get 5 mins for example:

**EDITED**

I have re-written the code following comments below changing other factors as well as the time comparison.

The code below is an example of how you could make this macro automatically delete new rows added. The code should be added to the sheet that you are making the changes on (rather than a module or the workbook). If you do not want to take the automatic approach then you could either add an option to check with the user first or just change the sub and pass in a range object representing a cell on the row that has just been added (let me know if you need help with this):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim newStr
    Dim newDate
    Dim prevStr
    Dim prevDate
    Dim interval

    newStr = Range("D" & Target.Row).Value
    newDate = Range("F" & Target.Row).Value
    prevStr = Range("D" & Target.Row - 1).Value
    prevDate = Range("F" & Target.Row - 1).Value
    interval = (1 / 24) / 12 ' 5 mins

    If newStr = prevStr And Abs(newDate - prevDate) <= interval Then
        Target.EntireRow.Delete
    End If

End Sub
```

I have set up some test data and the above seems to work nicely on the sample data that I have set up, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: The VBA didn't like the Cells.Value command, and then doesn't like If (Cells(i, "D") - Cells(i - 1, "D")) > (a) And (Cells(i, "F") = Cells(i - 1, "F")) Then    I'm wondering if Cells.Value is an actual command?  Is there a better method using Range instead?

Comment: OK, so I figured out that the .Value has to go after the Cells() portion, but it still gives me the runtime error 1004 for the line: If (Cells(Lrow, "D") - Cells(Lrow - 1, "D")) > (a) And Cells(Lrow, "F").Value = Cells(Lrow - 1, "F").Value Then

Comment: Sorry to say but this code has lots of problems and thus cannot be used. The indexing does not make any sense (where is i coming from?!) and you are deleting rows in the middle of a loop what, most likely, would provoke further errors. I am a true fan of "just answer the question and let the remaining code as it was orignally", but this time it is a horrible idea because the original code is too faulty. I am not a downvoter unless under extreme conditions (someone insulting or something like this) but you should improve your answer a bit because it seriously deserves a -1 IMO.

Comment: @varocarbas, thanks for the feedback, I will take another look. I did as you suggested just try to answer the main question asked.

Comment: OK, I've tried your code, but for some reason, it will 'save' in the VBA window, but when I try to run it, it opens the list of macros window, and it isn't there.  When I take out the (ByVal target as Range) it will save and be selectable, but then will have a runtime error 424 - object required.  For some reason, the VBA doesn't like the byval target as range piece.  Any advice?

Comment: Chris- ok, so I figured out that I needed to put this private sub in the worksheet portion, and not a module.  And it works, but I have to click on each cell for it to run.  Is there a way to make it into a macro that will automatically run down all of the rows?

Answer (score 1):

I see various problems, including some indices which do not seem to be right. Here you have an improved version (the loop is going now forwards because it seems to be more clear):

```
     Dim toDelete(10) As Integer 'Put same size than Lastrow rather than 10
     Dim toDeleteCount As Integer: toDeleteCount = -1
    'FirstRow has to be greater or equal than 2
    Firstrow = 2
    For Lrow = Firstrow To Lastrow Step 1

            'We check the values in the D column
             With Cells(Lrow, "D")
                If Not IsEmpty(.Value) Then

                    If ((CDate(Cells(Lrow, "D")) - CDate(Cells(Lrow - 1, "D")) > CDate("0:00:05")) And (Cells(Lrow, "F") = Cells(Lrow - 1, "F"))) Then
                        Cells(Lrow, "D") = ""
                        Cells(Lrow, "F") = ""
                        'You cannot delete the whole row inside the loop. Just delete the values in the cells you want or store the row number in a variable such that you can delete all the rows outside the loop
                        toDeleteCount = toDeleteCount + 1
                        toDelete(toDeleteCount) = Lrow
                    End If
                End If

            End With
        Next Lrow
        If (toDeleteCount >= 0) Then
           For Each rDelete In toDelete
              Rows(rDelete).Delete
           Next rDelete
        End If
```

Comment: Sorry for being a novice, but what type of variable would be able to store all of the row #'s so that they could be deleted outside of the loop?

Comment: An array for example. Or you might put all the numbers in a string variable separated by commas or slashes.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I tried running it and I get a run-time error '9': subscript out of range on the line "toDelete(toDeleteCount)=Lrow

Comment: Because you didn't dimensioned the array properly. Replace "10" with the value of Lastrow (as indicated in my comment). Also you can put an in-the-safest scenario condition: if toDeleteCount >= LastRow Exit For. While dealing with arrays you have to make sure that the code will not try to write in a position greater than the maximum length of the array.

Comment: OK, I'm missing something, when I put in Dim toDelete(Lastrow) as String, its telling me that a compile error -- constant expression required - I don't see where Lastrow is defined.

Comment: You can either put the number manually, declare Lastrow as a constant instead as a variable (Const Lastrow = 10) or rely on redimensioning (ReDim toDelete(Lastrow) As String). In any case, I guess that this small problems (not directly related with the question) can be found relatively easy after a quick research ;)

Comment: So, I put in ReDim toDelete(lastrow) as string.  Then when I run it, I get runtime error "13" type mismatch for Rows(rDelete).Delete.  Then I noticed that rDelete was never declared, so I put in the Dim rDelete as integer, which it didn't like, said it needed to be a variant to control an array, so I declared it as a variant, and still get a runtime error "13" type mismatch on the Rows(rDelete).Delete line.  I'm lost.

Comment: Relax, please! This time, it was my error: toDelete are row numbers, that is, integers (or longs if the number grows too big). This is the reason why you get a type mismatch, you are trying to delete a row indexed by a string. rDelete is declared; the for loop takes care of that. This was my error, no doubt on that; in any case, you should make sure that you understand the code properly before executing it.

Comment: Also bear in mind that the toDeleteCount starts in 0 (because the arrays are started in zero and so is easy for you) and thus the last condition should be totDeleteCount >= 0 (already updated it). When you come for help, you should understand the code/explanations as something to work on, not as an excuse to keep asking. I do intend to deliver properly working codes, but also don't think that I should be the one worrying about each single detail. The codes I deliver account for the most important problems in the question, any side issue should be taken care of by the asker (you)...

Comment: ... I am happy to help but neither I think that giving a permanent support for each single detail is of any help nor I feel too well when I have to take care of issues which can be easily fixed after 30seconds of Google research. So, please, show your gratitude in the way I personally like the most: proving that you have actually understood the problem and maximised the small bits of information I have provided. I hope that now everything is clear enough.

Comment: Varocarbas - I'm not complaining, I appreciate your help, and I am a novice in VBA programming, I'm learning as I go, and even google searching doesn't explain the ins and outs of why a particular piece of code is not working.  But, I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

OK, so after a bit more digging, I found this and modified it to work.

Thanks for your help Varocarbas and Chris!

```
Sub deleterows()
    Dim myrange, mycell As Range
    Dim myrow()
    Set myrange = Sheets("sheet5").Range("F2", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For Each mycell In myrange
        If mycell.Value = mycell.Offset(-1, 0).Value Then
            If mycell.Offset(0, -2).Value - mycell.Offset(-1, -2).Value <= TimeValue("00:00:05") Then
                q = q + 1
                ReDim Preserve myrow(q)
                myrow(q) = mycell.Row
            End If
        End If
    Next mycell
    For i = q To 1 Step -1
        p = myrow(i)
        myrange(p - 1, 1).EntireRow.Delete
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Glad you came to a good solution and hopefully learnt some new tricks along the way.

Comment: I am happy to see that you finally got the point. I hope that in the future you will  post more specific questions, easier to be answered and more helpful to anyone reading them (this question/answer is of true help just to you). But if all this has helped you to get a proper grasp of VBA, I guess that it has been worthy.